# Why are my sqlite calls on separate threads at the same time?

Tags: sqlite, swift, thread-safety

I have a class at https://github.com/AaronBratcher/ALBNoSQLDB that I am trying to make sure is thread safe. Sqlite requires that calls be made by only 1 thread at a time.

I have a queue called _dbQueue

```
private let _dbQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.AaronLBratcher.ALBNoSQLDBQueue", nil)
```

and I open the db synchronously on this queue

```
    ...
    var openDBSuccessful = true

    //create task closure
    let openFile:() = {
        openDBSuccessful = self.openDBFile(dbFilePath)
        }()

    dispatch_sync(_dbQueue) {
        openFile
    }
    ...
```

I also run commands and queries synchronously on the same queue

```
private func sqlExecute(sql:String)->Bool {
    var successful = true

    //create task closure
    let command:() = {
        successful = self.runCommand(sql)
        }()

    dispatch_sync(_dbQueue) {
        command
    }

    return successful
}

func sqlSelect(sql:String)->[DBRow]? { // DBRow is an array of AnyObject
    var recordset:[DBRow]?

    let query:() = {
        recordset = self.runSelect(sql)
        }()

    dispatch_sync(_dbQueue) {
        query
    }

    return recordset
}
```

When doing some testing however, I got this. Two separate threads running sqlite at the same time. How do I keep this from happening?

[image: exception error shown with stack]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite commands need to be run on the same thread. This can be accomplished in two ways:

a) run on the main thread

b) subclass NSThread and run your SQLite commands there

Dispatching from any given queue, except the main queue, does not guarantee that blocks will be executed on the same thread.

To fix this, I chose option b. Code can be found here:  https://github.com/AaronBratcher/ALBNoSQLDB